# C++11: Workaround Use Of This Incomplete Type Error?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

constexpr int N = 10;
constexpr int f(int x) { return x*2; }

typedef array<int, N> A;

template<int... i> struct F { constexpr A f() { return A{{ f(i)... }}; } };

template<class X, class Y> struct C;
template<int... i, int... j>
struct C<F<i...>, F<j...>> : F<i..., (sizeof...(i)+j)...> {};

template<int n> struct S : C<S<n/2>, S<n-n/2>> {}; // <--- HERE
template<> struct S<1> : F<0> {};

constexpr auto X = S<N>::f();

int main()
{
        cout << X[3] << endl;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
test.cpp:15:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct C<S<5>, S<5> >’
```

I suspect this is because the definition of S is using itself as a base class. (Correct?)

What is the best way to fix this?

**Update:**

Here is the fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

constexpr int N = 10;
constexpr int f(int x) { return x*2; }

typedef array<int, N> A;

template<int... i> struct F { static constexpr A f() { return A{{ ::f(i)... }}; } };

template<class A, class B> struct C {};
template<int... i, int... j> struct C<F<i...>, F<j...>> : F<i..., (sizeof...(i)+j)...>
{
        using T = F<i..., (sizeof...(i)+j)...>;
};

template<int n> struct S : C<typename S<n/2>::T, typename S<n-n/2>::T> {};
template<> struct S<1> : F<0> { using T = F<0>; };

constexpr auto X = S<N>::f();

int main()
{
        cout << X[3] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072359/c11-compile-time-array-with-logarithmic-evaluation-depth

Comment: doesnt compile. even c++11 does not allow ellipsis in so lot of places.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: I know it doesn't compile, I'm showing the compiler error.  It isn't related to the ellipses.

Comment: Changes introduced by @Andrew in updated version: **(1)** `struct C`'s primary template, rather then being declared, is now defined(with an empty definition). **(2)** `struct C`'s partial specialization now has a non-empty definition containing a template alias for inherited `struct F`. **(3a)** For inheriting structure `S`, `struct C`'s template arguments `S` now have a scope operator accessing template alias `T`. **(3b)** `typename` for scope operator. **(4)** Fully specialized `struct S`, `S<1>`, once empty definition, contains a template alias `using T=F<0>;` for `S<1>`'s inherited `F<0>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `C` instead of just declaring it.

```
template<class X, class Y> struct C {};
```

In the place you use it the partial specialization does not match and
the primary template is instantiated, which is just a declaration.

You may wonder why that specialization is not considered: specializations don't consider conversions, but just the static type. That's why they are so treacherously incompatible with inheritance.

Comment: Hmm, well that sucks.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling I meditated over what you are trying to do here but it doesn't make much sense to me. What is that code actually trying to achieve? I can figure out what `F` and `C`, do but the purpose of `S` eludes me.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072359/c11-compile-time-array-with-logarithmic-evaluation-depth

Comment: `S<N>` should give access to `F<0,1,2,...,N-1>` somehow with log(N) instantiation depth.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just delegate `S::f` instead of using inheritance?

```
template<int n> struct S {
    constexpr A f() { return C<S<n/2>, S<n-n/2>>::f(); }
};
```

Comment: `C<S<n/2>, S<n-n/2>>` needs to bind to the specialization `C<F<i...>,F<j...>>`, which it won't because template specialization doesn't consider inheritance.