# How to check duplicate types in a std::tuple in compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

I'd like to have the following helper:

```
is_duplicate< std::tuple<int, double, char, double, float > >::value
```

where value is:

- *true* when there are duplicates.
- *false* when there aren't duplicates.

I don't know how to recursively iterate the tuple to perform the check. I don't know that strategies exists to solve this problem.

Can someone explain me how to create this helper?

Comment: Try finding the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986560/check-variadic-templates-parameters-for-uniqueness

Comment: @AndreyNasonov: Thank you so much for the help