# Variadic templates: One method per template argument

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, member-functions

Is there a way to automatically create one method per variadic template argument?

For example, in the code below, I want to be forced to override `void x(a &v)` and `void x(b &v)` in `class i`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class a {
};

class b {
};

template <typename ...T>
class t {
public:
    virtual void x(T &v) = 0;
};

class i : public t<a, b>
{
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    i ii;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a `t_impl` that holds the virtual function for a single `T` like

```
template <typename T>
class t_impl
{
public:
    virtual void x(T &v) = 0;
};
```

and then `t` would inherit from it like

```
template <typename ...T>
class t : t_impl<T>... // can use public, protected or private inheritance
{
public:
    using t_impl<T>::x...; // used to import t_impl<T>::x into the public space
    // any additional common members
};
```

Comment: but to make `x()` usable given `t*`, you should add a `using` declaration.

Comment: Nice. This is more efficient than what I suggested (for compilation). We should also note that either the user can't list the same type twice, or we'd need to add something here to prevent a second inheritance in that case...

Comment: @Eugene Good call.  Code fixed.

Comment: @Elliott Yeah.  Adding a static assert with a check from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986560/check-variadic-templates-parameters-for-uniqueness) should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `t` a variadic template, just template it on a single type:

```
template <typename T>
class t {
public:
    virtual void x(T &v) = 0;
};
```

and inherit base classes like this instead:

```
class i : public t<a>, t<b>
{
    virtual void x(a &v) {}
    virtual void x(b &v) {}
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d67j6Y).