# How to create a concept to check if all the given type parameters are different in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

A concept which checks if the first given type parameter is different from the rest of type parameters is as following:

```
template<typename TYPE, typename ... TYPES>
concept different = ((not std::same_as<TYPE, TYPES>) and ...);
```

(`std::same_as` is from `<concepts>` standard library)

But how to check if all the given type parameters are different from each other?

Comment: Thanks to a comment I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043402/11434141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an example of the concept you can use :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename arg_t, typename... args_t>
static consteval bool all_unique()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args_t) == 0ul)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return (!std::is_same_v<arg_t, args_t> && ...) && all_unique<args_t...>();
    }
}

template<typename... args_t>
concept AllUnique = all_unique<args_t...>();

template<typename...args_t>
void f(args_t... args) requires AllUnique<args_t...>
{

}

int main()
{
    static_assert(all_unique<int>());
    static_assert(all_unique<int,bool>());
    static_assert(!all_unique<int, bool, int>());

    static_assert(AllUnique<int>);
    static_assert(AllUnique<int, bool>);
    static_assert(!AllUnique<int, bool, int>);

    f(1);
    f(1, true);
    // f(1, 2); // indeed does not compile
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but because I needed a concept, I liked this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043402/11434141 more. However both of them are based on a same method. I would appreciate it if you could edit your answer to include the concept as well.

Comment: @AKL Updated the example for you.