# how to initialize a fixed size array and assign elements with a constexpr function in C++11 or with help of boost

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically create static arrays at compile time in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c)

I have lots of data to be stored in a fixed array, with its elements depend on position. The value of each element can be calculated at compile time.

My code is almost like:

```
int fun(int p) // maybe constexpr
{
    return 0x1<<p;
}

int a[17] = {
    repeat_fun_from_0_to_16();
};
```

Since all of the value can be determined at compile time, there should be a way to do this, I guess.

I also checked out there's a `repeat()` in boost.assignment, but don't know how to use it with this situation.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108390/c11-compile-time-calculation-of-array and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c?lq=1 may help

Comment: Thanks, @aleguna ! I've figured out this with the second link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @aleguna , I've solved this problem by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c?lq=1).

All I need to change is the meta function:

```
template<size_t index> struct MetaFunc { 
    enum { value = index << 1 }; 
};
```